# Transaction fail if attribute not null in Rust

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to make a conditional check and update transaction in Rust that fails if an attribute is not null.

```
let check = ConditionCheck::builder()
            .key("id", AttributeValue::S(input.id()))
            .key(
                "sorted",
                AttributeValue::S(input.sorted()),
            )
            .table_name(dynamo_table)
            .condition_expression("exp = :val")
            .expression_attribute_values(":val", AttributeValue::Null(true))
            .build();
```

This conditional check doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are confusing Null with the condition if the attribute exists or not.

In DynamoDB Null is a data type, so your condition will only work if you have a value of Null:True.

If you want to your condition to only succeed if the attribute does not exist, then use `exists` condition.

`attribute_not_exists(exp)`